# Retrieving GPS coordinates not working when ran on a real android phone

Tags: java, android, gps

My program should be able to:

1. Change the map view
2. Zoom in to the phone's current location
3. Add a marker
4. Display an alert of the Latitude and Longitude values

When I use GPS_PROVIDER, functions 1-4 works in my emulator (because I manually feed it a latitude and longitude values). But when I created an apk file, 2-4 functions don't work.

Here's my class.

```
package com.locator.map;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class Main extends MapActivity
{
    MapController controller;
    double currentLat;
    double currentLon;
    LocationManager manager;
    boolean locationChanged = false;
    Button retrieveLocationButton, toggleViewButton;
    boolean streetview = false;
    Drawable d;
    List<Overlay> overlaylist;
    MapView map;
    Criteria criteria;
    String bestProvider;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      
        map = (MapView) findViewById (R.id.googleMap);       
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setSatellite(true);
        controller = map.getController();


        criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        manager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);        
        bestProvider = manager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieveLocation);
        toggleViewButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeView);

        retrieveLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {      
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    showCurrentLocation();
                }
        });        

        toggleViewButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (streetview == false)
                {
                    map.setSatellite(false);
                    map.setStreetView(true);
                    streetview=true;
                }
                else if (streetview == true)
                {
                    map.setStreetView(false);
                    map.setSatellite(true);
                    streetview=false;
                }
            }           
        });
        LocationListener listener = new LocationListener()
        {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //Retrieve the current GPS coordinates
                currentLat = location.getLatitude();
                currentLon = location.getLongitude();

                locationChanged = true;
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your GPS services are not activated.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your GPS services are now activated.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your GPS service provider is changed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        };

        manager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 1000, 1, listener); //--> To update current location (coordinates [latitude & longitude]).       

    }

    protected void showCurrentLocation()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //If location is changed or updated - Zoom in to current location, add a marker and show a dialog with current coordinates.
        if (locationChanged == true)
        {
            //Set the map's view and zoom level animation
            GeoPoint currentLocation = new GeoPoint ((int) (currentLat * 1E6), (int) (currentLon * 1E6));

            controller.setCenter(currentLocation);
            controller.setZoom(15);

            //Show the current coordinates (Convert to String and round off - 6 decimal places)
            String printLat = new DecimalFormat("0.######").format((double)currentLat);
            String printLon = new DecimalFormat("0.######").format((double)currentLon);

            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();
            alert.setTitle("Current Location:");
            alert.setMessage("Latitude: " + printLat + "\n" + "Longitude: " + printLon);
            alert.setButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {               
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Alert Dialog won't work without a listener
                    //Do nothing (This will simply close your alert dialog)
                }
            });     
            alert.show();

            //Add a marker
            overlaylist = map.getOverlays();
            d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);         
            CustomPinpoint marker = new CustomPinpoint (d, Main.this);          
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem (currentLocation, "1st String", "2nd String");
            marker.insertPinpoint(overlayitem);
            overlaylist.add(marker);    
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

I also tried using NETWORK_PROVIDER.
Everything works in my phone but it's not returning accurate latitude and longitude values. It adds marker but it's about 1 kilometer away from my actual location.

Here's my class using NETWORK_PROVIDER:

```
package com.locator.map;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class Main extends MapActivity
{
    MapController controller;
    double currentLat;
    double currentLon;
    LocationManager manager;
    boolean locationChanged = false;
    Button retrieveLocationButton, toggleViewButton;
    boolean streetview = false;
    Drawable d;
    List<Overlay> overlaylist;
    MapView map;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      
        map = (MapView) findViewById (R.id.googleMap);       
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setSatellite(true);
        controller = map.getController();


        manager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);        

        retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieveLocation);
        toggleViewButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeView);

        retrieveLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {      
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    showCurrentLocation();
                }
        });        

        toggleViewButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (streetview == false)
                {
                    map.setSatellite(false);
                    map.setStreetView(true);
                    streetview=true;
                }
                else if (streetview == true)
                {
                    map.setStreetView(false);
                    map.setSatellite(true);
                    streetview=false;
                }
            }           
        });
        LocationListener listener = new LocationListener()
        {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //Retrieve the current GPS coordinates
                currentLat = location.getLatitude();
                currentLon = location.getLongitude();

                locationChanged = true;
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your GPS services are not activated.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your GPS services are now activated.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your GPS service provider is changed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        };

        manager.requestLocationUpdates(NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, listener); //--> To update current location (coordinates [latitude & longitude]).       

    }

    protected void showCurrentLocation()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //If location is changed or updated - Zoom in to current location, add a marker and show a dialog with current coordinates.
        if (locationChanged == true)
        {
            //Set the map's view and zoom level animation
            GeoPoint currentLocation = new GeoPoint ((int) (currentLat * 1E6), (int) (currentLon * 1E6));

            controller.setCenter(currentLocation);
            controller.setZoom(15);

            //Show the current coordinates (Convert to String and round off - 6 decimal places)
            String printLat = new DecimalFormat("0.######").format((double)currentLat);
            String printLon = new DecimalFormat("0.######").format((double)currentLon);

            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();
            alert.setTitle("Current Location:");
            alert.setMessage("Latitude: " + printLat + "\n" + "Longitude: " + printLon);
            alert.setButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {               
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Alert Dialog won't work without a listener
                    //Do nothing (This will simply close your alert dialog)
                }
            });     
            alert.show();

            //Add a marker
            overlaylist = map.getOverlays();
            d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);         
            CustomPinpoint marker = new CustomPinpoint (d, Main.this);          
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem (currentLocation, "1st String", "2nd String");
            marker.insertPinpoint(overlayitem);
            overlaylist.add(marker);    
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.locator.map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"  android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="Locator" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />     
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="Locator" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>        
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I think, GPS is working here in my area, Google Maps application returns accurate location when I use it.
I tried using my application (both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER) in the same location where I used Google Maps:

1. NETWORK_PROVIDER still returns inaccurate result.
2. GPS_PROVIDER still doesn't work.

Please help me.

Comment: I assume GPS is enabled. Is that right?

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid - Yes. GPS is enabled.

Comment: What if you download an app called 'GPS Test' and run it at the same location you ran your app. Does the GPS Test app get satellites lock?

Comment: @azgolfer - Google Maps GPS feature works in my phone and in the same location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure Google Maps is using GPS as it's provider? I find that GMaps often shows locations (and pretty precise ones at times!) using only data from Wi-Fi and GSM antennaes... In that case, your code may never be called (until there's a GPS fix).

I would try adding

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                new MyLocationListener());
```

to your code (below the registration to get GPS updates), just to check that possibility.

**Edit**

Try changing ACCURACY_FINE to ACCURACY_HIGH

Comment: What will be the difference if I will be using NETWORK_PROVIDER?

It's not working on my emulator. I'll try it on my phone. Thanks.

Comment: NETWORK_PROVIDER is based on the different signal strengths detected by the antennaes on the device. Usually this is far less precise than GPS_PROVIDER, but it usually provides a result faster (GPS_PROVIDER waits until it gets a lock for 5 GPS satellites I think, and that can take long depending on the actual device, especially if you're indoors

Comment: I tried using NETWORK_PROVIDER. It worked. It retrieved my location fast.

Comment: How long does it usually take to retrieve a location using GPS_PROVIDER? I tried waiting for about 2 minutes, but it's still not working.

Comment: It's not necessarily a matter of time, for example, if you are indoors it may never get a fix. Aside from that, I was given to understand that the gps system can be selectivelly shut down for a region by the US government... I hope (and extremelly doubt) it's not your case. If possible, I would try the application outdoors and check if the problem persists.

Comment: Well, I have tried my application outdoors, the NETWORK_PROVIDER gave me an inaccurate result. I think it's almost a kilometer away from my actual location. But I still haven't tried using GPS_PROVIDER outside.

I will just leave a comment here after trying it, and I hope that you'll answer me back again.
I really appreciate your effort of spending time and having a good conversation here. You have given me a big help. Thanks, sir.

Comment: Google Maps application works fine here in my location.
Does it mean that I'm not in a "Shut Down Region"?

Comment: Being in one of those regions would be an extremelly weird coincidence I guess. Does the google maps app provide a beter (more precise) location than your app at any given time? If so, there may be something else wrong with your app. Tell me if you get a chance to try the GPS outdoors :)

Comment: Actually, Google Maps app provides an exact output of where I am, I tried my application in the same exact place (using NETWORK_PROVIDER), it didn't give me an accurate result. But when I tried using GPS_PROVIDER it did't work. Are the codes of my program really the problem here?

Comment: How are you testing the app? Are you wating for a Toast message to appear or see the result of pressing the button?

Comment: The app's mapview should zoom in to where I am, it should add a marker, and display a toast of my current latitude and longitude values. They're all working, but not the "exact" results. It's like a kilometer away from me.

Comment: But that's not done with the code above, is it? If you can, publish your entire code plus your Manifest file, and if possible the logcat output from the crash (if any). Without that, I can't help much further :(

Comment: It is. The only thing that is modified is the PROVIDER. The one that's above is using GPS_PROVIDER. The zoom and marker function don't work at all. But when I use NETWORK_PROVIDER, all 3 features work, but gives unaccurate result, just like what I have mentioned a while ago.
I'm going to update my question. Thanks.

Comment: It's been raining all day here in my place. I tried Google Maps in the same place (the same location with what's in my question), Google Maps was unable to locate me exactly, it's like it used a NETWORK_PROVIDER.

I tried to use my app with a NETWORK_PROVIDER, it gave me a result the same with what Google Maps gave.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ask for "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" in your manifest?

In any case, I doubt if having that code in an activity is the best way to implement a GPS Listener (why not use a Service?) but maybe I'm not seeing something specific to your application

Comment: Yes. I have that permission in my Manifest file. Please see my edited question, I included my Manifest file's persmissions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add tags in manifest

```
use-feature name="android.hardware.location.network" 
use-feature name="android.hardware.location.gps"
```